# Correct way to animate box-shadow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, box-shadow

Which is the correct syntax to animate the **box-shadow** property with jQuery?

```
$().animate({?:"0 0 5px #666"});
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### Direct answer

Using Edwin Martin's **[jQuery plugin for shadow animation](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/)**, which extends the `.animate` method, you can simply use the normal syntax with "boxShadow" and every facet of that - *color*, the *x- and y-offset*, the *blur-radius* and *spread-radius* - gets animated. It includes multiple shadow support.

```js
$(element).animate({ 
    boxShadow: "0px 0px 5px 3px hsla(100, 70%, 60%, 0.8)"
})
```

---

#### Using CSS animations instead

jQuery animates by changing the `style` property of DOM elements, which can cause surprises with specificity and moves style information out of your stylesheets.

I can't find browser support stats for CSS shadow animation, but you might consider using JS to apply an animation-based *class* instead of handling the animation directly. For example, you can define a box-shadow animation in your stylesheet:

```css
@keyframes shadowPulse {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
    }

    100% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
    }
}
    
.shadow-pulse {
    animation-name: shadowPulse;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

You can then use the native `animationend` event to synchronise the end of the animation with what you were doing in your JS code:

##### Vanilla JS:

```js
element.classList.add('shadow-pulse')
element.addEventListener('animationend', event => {  
    element.classList.remove('shadow-pulse')
    // do something else...
})
```

##### jQuery:

```js
$(element).addClass('shadow-pulse')
$(element).on('animationend', function(){    
    $(element).removeClass('shadow-pulse')
    // do something else...
})
```

Comment: I agree, the accepted answer hasn't been update recently. This plugin worked nicely for me.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work without errors using jQuery 1.9 anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Given that it only came out, what, a week ago(?), he probably hasn't updated it yet. Have a read through the [jQ1.9 upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) and the [shadow animation plugin's source](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/archive/jquery.animate-shadow.js) and see what methods need to be reworked, if it's urgent.

Comment: I used the archive you linked instead of the latest version of his plugin and it worked flawlessly. So that solved my problem thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: No worries, but - wow, that was completely accidental. I must have clicked on the wrong link. Maybe try the unminified 1.8 version; see if it was a minification error? Seems strange that the 1.7 version would work better than 1.8 with 1.9.

Comment: I've tried both unminified and the minified version yesterday and both gave me the same error. I'm just happy it works now I just hope I won't run into any of the problems that solved in 1.8. I also hope that Edwin will continue to develop this plugin as it seems to be the version with the least hassle to use out there.

Comment: Using with jQuery 1.8.3 and it works fine but be sure you set default box shadow (for example: none)  in your CSS...  Spent some time to figure it out.

Comment: @Si8 here's not the place for bug reports - contact Edwin Martin about that. Also "it doesn't work" is not a very informative bug report

Comment: Oh yeah sorry... I meant it doesn't animate the shadow and just displays the text. I will reach out to him. Thanks.

Comment: I am new to jQuery and JavaScript in general. I used I Edwin Martin's plugin and tried adding the CDN tag to the html template I have, and then in my `app.js`, I tried something like `$("#elementId").animate({boxShadow: ...});` and that didn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 30):

If you are using jQuery 1.4.3+ then you can take advantage of the cssHooks code that was added.

By using the boxShadow hook: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/boxshadow.js

You can do something like this:

```
$('#box').animate({
    'boxShadowX': '10px',
    'boxShadowY':'10px',
    'boxShadowBlur': '20px'
});
```

The hook doesn't let you animate the color yet but I am sure with some work that could be added.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/w5aAn/

Comment: Are cssHooks part of 1.4.3 or a plugin?  I'd love a link to some jQuery documentation if you've got one, this sounds interesting.

Comment: @Surreal Part of 1.4.3. cssHooks haven't been documented much yet but you can dive in to the sorce and check it out: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js  Brandon Arron has been doing a lot of playing with cssHooks: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/

Comment: @Blowsie probably is a problem with the boxshadow cssHook. Maybe same as this problem: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/issues/32

Comment: This doesn't seem to support inset box-shadows, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @AdamFraser works for me (tested in Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/w5aAn/474/

Comment: Ah, that works. So you just need to specify `inset` beforehand. Got it.

Comment: FYI: @tomeoftom's answer is more modern and works exceptionally well.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use a plugin, it can be done with a bit of CSS:

```
#my-div{    
  background-color: gray;
  animation: shadowThrob 0.9s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation: shadowThrob 0.9s ease-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes shadowThrob {
  from {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.9);}
  to {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.2);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes shadowThrob {
  from {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.9);}
  to {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.2);}
}
/*NOTE: The animation property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.*/
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8E5U/

If you want full documentation on CSS animations, your path to wizardry [begins here..](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)

Comment: Nice one, indeed. Somehow, this one doesn't burn most of my processor running the animation. I think, but I'm not sure though, that it was due to the fact that I used 2 ranges of **percentage** for the keyframes (0%, 50% and 100%).

Answer (score 4):

I love the ShaneSauce solution !
Use a class intead of an ID and you can add/remove the effect to any element using jQuery addClass/delay/removeClass :

```
$('.error').each( function(idx, el){
    $( el )
        .addClass( 'highlight' )
        .delay( 2000 )
        .removeClass( 'highlight' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it without a plugin: [jQuery animated Box](http://www.crimson-cardinal.com/blog/programming-jquery-animated-boxes123)  But it doesn't have the extra functionality that comes with the use of a plugin, but I personally like to see (and understand) the method behind the madness.