# jQuery box shadow animation - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct way to animate box-shadow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery)

How to use the animate() function?

I tried this solution:
[Correct way to animate box-shadow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery)

like

```
...
  .animate({
    marginTop: '-20px',
    marginLeft: '-20px',
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
   'boxShadowX': '10px',
   'boxShadowY':'10px',
   'boxShadowBlur': '20px'
  }, 200);
...
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provided is using https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/raw/master/boxshadow.js, make sure you are calling the script.

You can also checkout the excellent jQuery Shadow animation plugin http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/

Comment: thanks, that works :D but not in opera :(

Comment: The author claims it's an opera bug. I can't test it from my side. You're animation should work. I think you forget to call the boxshadow.js script, I included the link in my answer.