# Animate box-shadow with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

BoxShadow not working

$(document).ready(function () {
let r, g, b, rBorder, gBorder, bBorder, top, left;

```
setInterval(function () {
    r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    rBorder = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    gBorder = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    bBorder = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    top = Math.round(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
    left = Math.round(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);

    $('.element')
        .css({
            border: '0px solid #fff',
            boxShadow: `0px  green`
        })
        .animate({
            backgroundColor: `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`,
            borderWidth: '2px',
            borderColor: `rgb(${rBorder}, ${gBorder}, ${bBorder})`,
            boxShadow: `0px 0px 30px 0px rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`,
            top: top,
            left: left
        }, 2000, 'linear');
});
```

});

Comment: theres already a question for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547012/jquery-box-shadow-animation-is-it-possible

the best solution is to install a jquery plugin