# Working method to animate box-shadow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css

Im asking this in reference to [the previous thread of the same vein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery), which contains a number of outdated non-working solutions and as well as [the jquery box-animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/) which is restricted to one box. Does anyone know how to animate the box-shadow of multiple elements?

Comment: `$('#box1').animate({boxShadow: '0 0 30px #44f'});` can't you add the ID field of multiple items. `$('#box1')..` `,$('#box2')..`, `$('#box3')..`

Comment: and Now that I'm looking at it, the page you linked allows more than one box to be animated. but I would get away from using onMouseOver as the eventhandlers work different from browser to browser.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it looks like you can, just not from within a script, it only seems to work as the example is, by putting it directly within the element.

Answer (score 5):

you can use **CSS3** `transition`:

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ererax/26/edit)*

```
.box {
    background: #1c1c1c;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:20px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-out;
}
 
.box:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444;
}
```

P.S, instead of `s` *(seconds)* you can use: `ms` *(millis)*.

Comment: This is much easier to use than the other script he was referencing to. Now all he has to do is add class to each element.

Comment: @Kyle Monti -I don't understand, why to add class? What one is the easyest way?

Comment: I was considering this, however css3 transitions cut out ie9 and below, which is like 50% of the market, not a very wise idea to use until 9 becomes obsolete, at least not for anything significant.