# jQuery slowly fade in inset boxshadow

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to slowly fade in a inset box shadow.
 I don't want to use a css3 transition, so please don't suggest it.

My html:

```
<ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ingredients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The jQuery i've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav li').fadeIn('1000', function () {
    $(this).css('boxShadow', 'inset', '0px', '0px', '5px', '2px', '#EBEBEB' );
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery The accepted answer is appropriate here

Comment: You can follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery

Answer (score -1):

You can use .animate instead of .css.
It might not be work as you are applying .animate function to box-shadow so You can use box-shadow animate plug-in to work across the browser.

Comment: `.animate()` only animates sacalar (numeric) values. Seeing as `box-shadow` has no longhand properties this isn't possible