# jquery box-shadow not applied

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code:

```
$("#my_div").animate({
      "margin-left": "-145px",
      "background-color": "#ffffff",
      "width": "1240px",
      "padding": "6px 6px 6px 6px",
      "border-radius": "6px",
      "box-shadow": "0px 0px 9px #323232",
      "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 0px 9px #323232"
}, 1000);
```

But the `box-shadow` and `padding` styles aren't applied.
I can't spot the error...

Comment: For CSS property, you can only animate one single value. e.g, you should use padding-left,padding-top,etc...

Comment: you are absolutely right... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#my_div").animate({
      "margin-left": "-145px",
      "background-color": "#ffffff",
      "width": "1240px",
      "padding": "6px 6px 6px 6px",
      "border-radius": "6px",
      boxShadow: "0px 0px 9px #323232", //change here
      paddingTop:'6px',
      paddingLeft:'6px',
      paddingRight:'6px',
      paddingBottom:'6px',
}, 1000);
```

Reference: [Correct way to animate box-shadow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery#9197026)