# How i can do to animate shadow of the element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I don't know syntax for animate shadow in webkit browsers.

```
$("#id").animate({-webkit-box-shadow: '0 0 1rem white'}, 1000);
```

od

```
$("#id").animate({boxShadow: '0 0 1rem white'}, 1000);
```

or

```
$("#id").animate({'-webkit-box-shadow': '0 0 1rem white'}, 1000);
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: is jQuery animate necessary ? if not then use Css animation . because css performance is very good

Comment: @MaulikAnand, i have a small browser game, and i need pick some elements(control elements) for user before start game(training). I do not know which way is better to use?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja, i test this solution, but nothing happens too...

Comment: I recommend **[Velocity js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)** . it performs better then CSS, especially in high stress situation, if you are developing game then the performance is key

Comment: this link should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits [Correct way to animate box-shadow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery)

**Solution # 1 - JQuery:**

You can check out Edwin Martin's **[jQuery plugin for shadow animation](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/)**. It extends the `.animate` method, so you can simply use the normal syntax with "boxShadow" and every facet of that  like color, the x- and y-offset, the blur-radius and spread-radius:

```
$(selector).animate({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
```

**Solution # 2 - CSS:**

```
#my-div{    
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width:  100px;
    background-color: #eee;
    animation: shadowThrob 5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation: shadowThrob 5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes shadowThrob {
    from {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.9);}
    to {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.2);}
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes shadowThrob {
    from {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.9);}
    to {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(190,65,12, 0.2);}
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed this:

```
/* Standard syntax */
animation: shadowThrob 5s;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation: shadowThrob 5s;
```

To make it stop after 5 seconds... Also added some comments for browser compatibility in the code

**JSFiddle: (Updated)**

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/QjLQ3/2)

Comment: how i can add eventhandlers for start and stop this animation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the animation is still running inifinity

Comment: Edited the answer again.. sorry I missed the -webkit part... Check the new demo

Comment: @user3739658 -1! **strongly avoid just copying other's answer**. Even if you do this for reference, give proper credit to the original Author!

I ca see it is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133366/correct-way-to-animate-box-shadow-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can simply animate (transition) `box-shadow` directly in a modern web-kit browser. No need for any browser extensions:

```
#myBox {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px 0 #CCCCCC;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7SRUE/