# How to use box-shadow with jQuery animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, box-shadow

I have a an li element which needs to animate to box shadow on hover but I am not able to get the desired results here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#skill_list li').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: "-5px",
        boxShadow: "10px 10px red"
    }, 100, "linear").clearQueue();
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: "0px",
        boxShadow:"0px 0px"
    }, 100, "linear").clearQueue();
})
});
```

Thankyou

Comment: What are your desired results? What is actually happening when you run the code you have?

Comment: I know you've asked for a jQuery solution, but would you be open to a css only solution? [jQuery is widely known to be quite slow when it comes to animation performance](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/#article-header-id-1\)

Comment: @RyanWilson the box shadow is not animating,when I inspect the element I see the position property being changed but not the box shadow

Comment: @Ghostrydr sure I can try css also,actually I am learning jquery so I wanted solution in jQuery

Comment: @KashyapPavra probably because in your second .animate() you don't change the boxShadow property, in fact, it is not there at all.

Comment: @RyanWilson even after changing boxShadow in 2nd animate() does not show any effect

Comment: @KashyapPavra Please update your post to reflect what you changed in the 2nd animate()

Comment: @RyanWilson I have made the changes in the post

Answer (score 0):

#### Direct answer

Using Edwin Martin's **[jQuery plugin for shadow animation](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/)**, which extends the `.animate` method, you can simply use the normal syntax with "boxShadow" and every facet of that - *color*, the *x- and y-offset*, the *blur-radius* and *spread-radius* - gets animated. It includes multiple shadow support.

```
$(element).animate({ 
  boxShadow: "0px 0px 5px 3px hsla(100, 70%, 60%, 0.8)"
});
```

**Using CSS**

```
.element{
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.element:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px hsla(100, 70%, 60%, 0.8); 
}
```

Comment: I have used this method but it does not seem to work in m case

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197026/5707563

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your css and add it wherever you want

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}
.box {
  transition: box-shadow .3s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  
}
.box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2); 
}
```

Comment: Why does this helps or answer the question that explicit says "jQuery" ?

Comment: thankyou so much your method worked flawlessly,can you tell me how this can be done using jquery also?